# How to wait core data add functions step by step in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have `coredata` tables and when user login want to insert big datas inside them. I have core data add function and I have `PKHUD` loading I try to use them but function **dont wait** to complete all data insert , going Profile `viewcontroller`, I want to wait function when core data adding complete with `PKHUD` loading after continue .. How can I resolve it ?
 my codes under below.

```
       @IBAction func login (sender: UIButton){

         if prefs.string(forKey: "name") == "John"{
  }else{ 
   if prefs.string(forKey: "adddata") == "yes"{

        // LOADING BAR STARDED
         PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView = PKHUDProgressView()
         PKHUD.sharedHUD.show()

         // HERE MY ADD CORE DATA FUNCTIONS
         coreDataAdd(where : "User")
         coreDataAdd(where : "Profile")
         coreDataAdd(where : "Games")


 if prefs.string(forKey: "go") == "yes"{

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                                        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile") as! profileViewController
                                        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

}

      // LOADING BAR END
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide(animated:false);
          }
}

}
}
```

My function under below

```
 func coreDataAdd(where : String) {


        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]

        let parameters = [
            "user": "\(prefs.string(forKey: "user")!)"
            ] as [String : String]
        Alamofire.request(geturl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .responseData{ response in
                let json = JSON(data:response.result.value!)  
                let success = json["Success"]["status"].boolValue
                let addJson = json["\(where)_list"].array

                if success == true {

                    if where == "User" {
                   for users in addJson! {
                           let addUser =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "\(where)", into:context) as! User
                            addUser.id = users["id"].int32Value
                            addUser.name = users["name"].stringValue
                            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
                     }

                    }



                }else{


                }
                  }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using completion handler for your function  or may try Operation queue with dependency to wait

```
    coreDataAdd (where : "User", onCompletion: { (isFinished) in
       if isFinished {
          coreDataAdd (where : "Profile", onCompletion: { (isFinished) in
          if isFinished { 
          coreDataAdd (where : "Profile", onCompletion: { (isFinished) in
            if isFinished
            //Here segue to the next view
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                                    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile") as! profileViewController
                                    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

       })
       } 
       }

       })
    })



    func coreDataAdd(where : String, onCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {


    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "text/html",
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

    let parameters = [
        "user": "\(prefs.string(forKey: "user")!)"
        ] as [String : String]
    Alamofire.request(geturl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
        .responseData{ response in
            let json = JSON(data:response.result.value!)  
            let success = json["Success"]["status"].boolValue
            let addJson = json["\(where)_list"].array

            if success == true {

                if where == "User" {
               for users in addJson! {
                       let addUser =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "\(where)", into:context) as! User
                        addUser.id = users["id"].int32Value
                        addUser.name = users["name"].stringValue
                        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

                 } 
                onCompletion(true)
                }



            }else{


            }
              }

}
```

Comment: can you give me answer with my codes i will est after i will approve your answer if it works ty

Answer (score -1):

Use a `NSFetchedResultsController` it will track core data change and has delegate callbacks to tell you when to change your tableview.

Comment: the saving code would remain the same, but your tableview code which you did not post (where I assume you doing a fetch) would change.  do a search for `NSFetchedResultsController` and read the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is you are making async call in `coreDataAdd` method(as it should be as they are network calls). The requirement for you is to stop  PKHUD loader after completion of every network call.

You can use [dispatch_group](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) for that purpose. Inside dispatch_group_notify, ask `main queue` to hide the loader.

Comment: how can I do it , ? can you show it with my codes ?

Comment: do you have any specific question about the solution I wrote?